# Sphere with three Möbius strips glued and sphere with a handle and a Möbius strip glued

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, klein-bottle, mobius-band

I am reading the first chapter from Topology by Armstrong. There, after stating the classification theorem for closed surfaces, he has mentioned an example that a sphere with one handle and one Möbius strip glued is homeomorphic to a sphere with three Möbius strips glued.

I am not able to see this. I know that to prove the above is to say that a torus with a Möbius strip glued is homeomorphic to a Klein bottle with a Möbius strip glued. How do I prove this? Or how do I at least convince myself that this is the case, in case I don't yet have the tools to prove it.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Euler characteristic of a surface and how it changes when taking connected sums?

Comment: No I dont know much about it. Is there not a direct approach?

Comment: Polygonal models of surfaces should be enough to prove this. The torus is a square with opposite sides identified in natural way. The Moebius band is a square with a pair of opposite sides identified in an unnatural way. Connected sums can be performed by chopping off a vertex on each diagram (leaving a short edge in its place) and identifing these new edges. Then some cutting and pasting may be necessary to bring the two connected sums to the same polygonal form.

Answer (score 2):

Each compact surface (except the sphere) has a standard [fundamental polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_polygon) representation, and each surface belongs to one of the two categories (non-orientable) $mP^2$ or (orientable) $nT^2$. For example, a torus ($T^2$) has a standard representation $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$, see the following figure:

[image: Fundamental polygon of the torus]

To construct the connected sum between two surfaces, we cut off a corner from each fundamental polygon, then glue the two polygons along the cut off edge. This is a process of concatenating (or inserting) the standard representation of one surface to another. For example, if you glue two torus handles you get a new representation like:

$$aba^{-1}b^{-1}cdc^{-1}d^{-1}$$

This is the standard representation of a $2T^2$, that is, a genus $2$ torus (a torus with two holes).

Back to your question, a Mobius band is a (real) projective space with a disc cut. It has a [triangle representation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1880686/orbit-space-of-torus-homeomorphic-to-mobius-strip):

[image: Fundamental polygon of the Mobius band]

Glue the third edge of this triangle with the torus handle, we get a new representation:

$$abcca^{-1}b^{-1}$$

See the following figure:
[image: Connected sum of torus and the projective space]

This representation has an edge pair $cc$ indicating that it belongs to the non-orientable category, and it has a single vertex class thus it has $6$ edges in its standard representation, implying that it is a $3P^2$. That is we've shown that the connected sum between $T^2$ and $P^2$ is

$$T^2\#P^2=3P^2$$

Answer (score 0):

See the proof of Lemma 7.1 in Massey's "A Basic Course in Algebraic Topology" (1991), pp 23-25.

Comment: Could you summarize the basic idea of the proof here? It would be helpful for people without immediate access to the textbook.

Answer (score 0):

Mobius strip allows access into the inside surface of the sphere. So slide one end of the g-handle into the strip and and it will then become attached to the sphere from the inside surface. That effectively turns the g-handle into a klien bottle and every such bottle is made up of two mobius strips.

So there, the three mobius strips you mentioned.