# What's the quotient space of torus $S^1\times S^1$ under equivalence relation $(z,w)\sim (w,z)$

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Consider the quotient space of torus $S^1\times S^1$ under the equivalence relation $(z,w)\sim (w,z)$.
I'm trying to visulaize it but find it pretty hard to do. Any hint?

Comment: A Möbius band, I think. The edge of the Möbius band would be the set $\{ (z,z) : z\in S^1\}/{\sim} \,. \qquad$

Comment: I asked this question before here and someone provided a nice visualization. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1909793/291100 if you look in the related links there’s an answer (to another question) that links to my question that provided a parameterization of the homeomorphism even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identify the torus $S^1\times S^1$ with the square $[0,1]^2$ modulo the identification of $(0,w)$ with $(1,w)$ and $(z,0)$ with $(z,1).$ Then you can identify the quotient space by your equivalence relation with $\{(z,w)\in[0,1]^2 : z\ge w\}.$ Now let
\begin{align}
u & = z+w-1 \\
v & = -z+w+1 \\[12pt]
\text{so that } z & = \frac{u-v} 2 + 1 \\[8pt]
\text{and } w & = \frac{u+v} 2
\end{align}
and reduce $z$ and $w$ modulo $1.$ Then you can view $(u,v)$ as being in the square $[0,1]^2$ modulo the identification of $(0,v)$ with $(1,1-v),$ and that quotient space is a Möbius band.